# Trouble with Decorator pattern, iOS / UICollectionViewCells

Tags: iphone, ios, design-patterns, decorator, uicollectionview

I am trying to 'decorate' UICollectionViewCells using the Decorator pattern.

For example, if I have a

```
 BaseCell : UICollectionViewCell
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
 BaseCell *cell = [[BaseCell alloc] initWithFrame]
 cell = [[GlowingCell alloc] initWithCell:cell];
 cell = [[BorderedCell alloc] initWithCell:cell];
 cell = [[LabelledCell alloc] initWithCell:cell];

 // cell is now a glowing, bordered, labelled cell.
```

I think the Decorator pattern is pretty neat for this sort of thing, but I'm having difficulty applying it to collection views.

Firstly, in UICollectionViewControllers you need to register a class, like this:

```
 [self.collectionView registerClass:cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

So I don't have an opportunity to make my own instance.

Secondly, I can't see how the Decorator can ever be useful for decorating 'non-pure' objects, that is, objects that I didn't create from the ground up but have their own properties and behaviours (such as UICollectionViewCell).  Since in the example above, `cell` represents a new instance of LabelledCell, and if UICollectionView makes a call on a method, eg, `isSelected`, this will call `aLabelledCellInstance.isSelected` unless I specifically do this in my Decorator base class:

```
 - (BOOL)isSelected {
      return self.decoratedCell.isSelected;
 }
```

Which is fine for one method but it doesn't seem right to have to override every method in `UICollectionViewCell`.  Should I be using `forwardInvocation:`?

Am I abusing this pattern, and are there alternatives?  Because it works very nicely in books when you just have to override basic methods like

```
 getPrice() {
      return decoratedObject.getPrice() + 1.10f;
 }
```

.. but seems hard to fit to the purpose of actually decorating existing UI elements with custom behaviour.

Thanks

EDIT:  What I am trying to avoid is having classes like this:

- GlowingBorderedCell
- LabelledGlowingBorderedCell
- etc.

On paper the Decorator is the perfect candidate for what I am trying to achieve but the implementation is absolutely stumping me.

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I like the thought about applying it to UI items. From an implementation standpoint, you question about if you are abusing the pattern, really depends on readability and maintainability. If using this pattern (even with overriding a lot of methods) make you code more readable and maintainable, then do it. If it obscures the intent and functionality of the code and makes it harder to change for the next guy, then don't

Comment: That's one of the main uses for it.

Comment: @Rob, I understand the purpose of design patterns, but in Sam's case, he's having to do additional, potentially less maintainable work to get the solution working. I was trying to give Sam a basis for what is essentially a judgement call

Comment: I wasn't criticizing, I was just stating the fact that Decorator is most often used for ui stuff like he's asking about.

Comment: Having to delegate all the methods does seem like a drag, though you could do a pragma and some code folding. That is how Decorator works. I have thought about ideas like this, I think they are good. So you can't register your own class? How is that? Isn't that the whole point of them asking for a class to instantiate?

Comment: You register a class type, not a decorated instance.  And having to delegate all the methods on a *system* class is what sets off alarm bells for me.

Comment: But your Decorator should be able to stand in as the class type. That's the whole idea.. ? A great interview question on DPs is 'Does Decorator delegate or implement the interface of the thing it's decorating?' The answer is both (and almost no one ever gets that).

Comment: Ah apologies, you are correct, but the internal implementation of `UICollectionView` will instantiate bare `BaseCell` objects, I need to create the instances myself.

Comment: Yeah, that's a faux pas on their part. I think your plan looks good. +1 the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the Decorator pattern requires you to override all the base methods in the `BaseDecorator` so you can forward the calls to the decorated object.
And you can do this either by overriding every single method or, preferably, just use `forwardInvocation:`. And since all other decorators will be subclasses of `BaseDecorator`, you can now just override the methods you want to change.

Secondly, for the `CollectionView` issue, I suggest to use the Decorator pattern with normal `UIView`s, and then use the decorated view as the `contentView` of the cell.
Let's see an example:

We have `BaseCellView` class which will be the super class for all decorators.

```
BaseCellView : UIView;
GlowingCellView: BaseCellView;
BorderedCell: BaseCellView;
LabelledCell: BaseCellView;
```

And we still have our `BaseCell` class which is a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
BaseCell : UICollectionViewCell;
```

Now, `UICollectionViewControllers` will always create an instance of `BaseCell` and give you the chance to configure it, where you'll do the following:

```
BaseCellView *cellView = [[BaseCellView alloc] initWithFrame]
cellView = [[GlowingCellView alloc] initWithCellView:cellView];
cellView = [[BorderedCellView alloc] initWithCellView:cellView];
cellView = [[LabelledCellView alloc] initWithCellView:cellView];
cell.contentView = cellView;
```

And you still can forward any `UICollectionViewCell` to the decorator if you want that.

Comment: This right here is why I love StackOverflow.  Great answer, I'm going to try this. Thanks!

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, I ended up not using this pattern because I need access to the various cell properties after creation and didn't want to include them all in the base decorator interface- I'm just sticking to a more rigid design for now.

Comment: I think you can pass a pointer to `Cell` to the initializer of `CellView`, so every `CellView` can access the properties of the cell it decorates. But you may start feeling it becomes a hackish solution.

Comment: Not only this but allocating all the decorator views on a configureCell rather than reusing, is sub-optimal

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://cocoaexposed.com/post/40353790996/advanced-delegation-decorator-pattern)'s a post in which I've described this technique. Although I've chosen to decorate the `UITableView` and not the cell, it could be easily adapted to your collection view. It's a pretty long read so I will only make a short summary here:

- the decorator needs to be a proxy object to be able to forward all the messages to the decorated object
- there are multiple methods you need to override in your decorator to make that happen, among which `respondsToSelector` and `forwardingTargetForSelector`
- when done, you'll be able to chain the decorators which is pretty neat:

e.g.:

```
dec = [[DEFooterDecorator alloc] initWithDecoratedObject:dec];
dec = [[DEHeaderDecorator alloc] initWithDecoratedObject:dec];
dec = [[DEGreenCellDecorator alloc] initWithDecoratedObject:dec];
```